# Hide list Sharepoint temporarily with Javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, hide

Back again with a javascript question within sharepoint. I would like to hide a list temporarly while my javascript code is running. So lets say I have a to do list.

Hide the list

I run my javascript code (doesn't matter what it is, so plz don't ask).

Show the list

I know how to do it with a calendarview but not listview yet:

HIDE CALENDAR-->$(".ms-cal-gempty").hide();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("table.ms-listviewtable").hide();
```

Comment: does this filter the cwep I add to put this code or the list I want to filter?

I got it already with some small modification.

THX!

Comment: Nope. It will only hide the table rendering your list.

Comment: Wonder though if list is loaded before cwep is loaded, since the cwep is underneath the list.